# Making a request every minute using React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an app that allows users to search Tweets about a particular topic. When searched, the Tweets will render on to a list. Once all the Tweets are rendered to the list I want the app to automatically load the new tweets on to the list w/o the user having to do anything. I am attempting to do this by having a setTimeOut function fetching from the API every minute but it just ends up being an infinite loop. How can i achieve this? Doing it with Redux.

List Component

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.tweets !== this.props.tweets) {
      try {
        setInterval(async () => {
          this.props.fetchPosts(this.props.symbol);
        }, 3000);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: i think it is better to share more code so its much easier to figure out what's the causing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your problem is with the `if` condition, if you are comparing two objects, the result in this case of `prevProps.tweets !== this.props.tweets` always be true, which will trigger a loop. In this case you have to compare in another way, like `JSON.stringify()`. Example:

```js
let a = { attr1: 1, attr2: 2 };
let b = { attr1: 1, attr2: 2 };

// Comparing two objects with '==='
console.log(a === b) // false

// Comparing two objects with 'JSON.stringify()'
console.log(JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)) // true
```

Ref: [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: The root problem of the question is the use of `componentDidUpdate`, not the way the props are compared. We can assume that `mapStateToProps` already recognizes the changed tweets correctly.

Comment: In the docs of `componentDidUpdate`, they explicit and have an example, with fetch, and they say it must be wrapped in `if`. In this case, it has a `if`, but it is always true, so it is like I don't have a `if`, with that, they say that it can cause an infinite loop, that was occurring, according to the question. That's why I said that the problem can be the way he compared the `props`.

Comment: In the React docs under https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate they use the same if condition and the `!==` check, so the comparison with `prevProps` and `props` would've been correct actually.

Comment: But, they compare a userId, a attribute, not a entire object. Run the code in my answer or in your devtools, you will see the difference when you compare a variable with a primitive type and a object.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now, you're right. It would've triggered the same interval again and again.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem I have tried to solve with the "right" comparison for objects haha :D

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `componentDidUpdate`, and instead just let react-redux take care of putting the new posts into the component. Since this polling every minute runs forever, until you don't see the component anymore, `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` are your friends.

```
intervalID = null;

componentDidMount() {
    // Poll once every minute for new posts
    this.intervalID = setInterval(
        () => this.props.fetchPosts(this.props.symbol),
        60 * 60
    );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalID);
}
```